# Capture the requested parallel jobs in CMake

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to capture the user-specified number of parallel build jobs with the `--parallel/-j` options in CMake?

I realise you can specify this in CMake with [`CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html#envvar:CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL), but I am wondering how I can access the user's requested number within my CMake file.

Comment: "how I can access the user's requested number within my CMake file." - It seems, you out of luck. The `CMakeLists.txt` is executed at *configuration* stage, but the user's value is known only on *build* stage. [Generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), used for provide some build-stage information for `CMakeLists.txt`, don't contain an expression which expose the number of parallel jobs.